# Eclipse Type Filters on the project level

Tags: eclipse

I know you can apply Type Filters on Eclipse to exclude some classes/packages from quick asset and types auto-complete , is there any thing to apply this on a specific project rather than globally ?

Comment: Try pulling your project into a new workspace and put your filters. And you can switch between different workspace. hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **access to certain class/packages can be forbidden on project level**. Forbidden classes are not displayed in auto-completion, nor can they be used.

For example, to forbid access to the `java.awt` package and its subpackages, do the following:

1. Goto ***Project > Properties: Java Build Path***, tab ***Libraries***
2. Select the node *Modulepath/Classpath > JRE System Library [...] > **Access rules*** and click ***Edit...***
3. In the *Type Access Rules* dialog click ***Add...***
4. Keep ***Forbidden*** as *Resolution* and enter the *Rule Pattern* **`java/awt/**`**

The access rules are saved in the project file `.classpath`.